# It says 'module' object has no type attribute when I'm trying to use event.type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

It says this when I'm trying to use event.type. I have not used the event module before though, but it says in my book that it is supposed to work. I looked this up, on google and on stack overflow, but I didn't find anything like this (I used Javascript for the code snippet, because i didn't know how to get the code into python.)

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
pygame.event.get()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
playercoords_a = (275,425)
playercoords_b = (275,475)
playercoords_c = (225,475)
playercoords_d = (225,425)
playertotalcoords = (playercoords_a, playercoords_b, playercoords_c, playercoords_d)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500),0,32)
windowSurface.fill(black)
xmod = 0
ymod = 0
pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface,white,((275,425),(275,475),(225,475),(225,425)))
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    if event == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            print('it works')
        windowSurface.fill((black,))
        pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface,white,((275 + xmod,425 + ymod),(275 + xmod,475 + ymod),(225 + xmod,475 + ymod),(225 + xmod,425 + ymod)))
        pygame.display.update()
```

> line 19, in 
>      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'type'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pygame, you usually have a `for` loop for event handling, and in your case it should look like this:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print('it works')
...
```

In this case, event is an event object returned from `pygame.event.get()` and not an module.

---

What you do is importing pygame's `event` module into the global namespace with `from pygame import *`. So when you run

```
while True:
    if event == KEYDOWN:
```

`event` is actually this very module, and not an acutal event object.

Never do `from pygame import *`.

Comment: Thanks! The code was actually: `from pygame.local import *`